# Create a dictionary where the key is a key from a dictionary and the value is a value from another key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking to create a dictionary where the key is `store` and the value is `store_type` in a nested dictionary.  I'd like it to output a dictionary with the keys and value of `store` : `store_type`.

I've tried but can't get `store` and `store_type` to return without getting a Type or Attribute Error:

```
def get_store(large_dict):
    for i in large_dict:
        name = i["store"]
        party = i["store_type"]
```

Sample code below

```
    "parent": 116,
    "child": 2,
    "group": "member",
    "bucket_number": 130,
    "source": "https://www.webiste.com/",
    "url": "hhttps://www.website.com/",
    "preference": {},
    },
    {
    "order": 3241235,
    "store": "Target",
    "description": "Expect More, Pay Less",
    },
    "previous_orders": [
        {
            "order_id": "0213124",
            "store": "Target",
            "store_type": "Retail",
            "state": "AL",
        },
        {
            "order_id": "0213125",
            "store": "Publix",
            "store_type": "Grocery",
            "state": "AL",
        },
        {
            "order_id": "0213126",
            "store": "Winn-Dixie",
            "store_type": "Grocery",
            "state": "AL",
        },
        {
            "order_id": "0213127",
            "store": "Sur la Table",
            "store_type": "Retail",
            "state": "AL",
        },
        {
            "order_id": "0213128",
            "store": "Trader Joes",
            "store_type": "Grocery",
            "state": "AL",
        }
```

Comment: Show your traceback

Answer (score 1):

What is the `for i in large_dict:` for? I'm having a hard time telling what the title of this question is asking, but it looks like you want to just do something like this.

```py
new_dict = {}

for order in large_dict["previous_orders"]:
    store = order["store"]
    store_type = order["store_type"]
    new_dict[store] = store_type
```

Comment: That probably means `large_dict` is not a dictionary. You may want to check that it is in fact what you were expecting.

Comment: Yeah, so I've tried creating a dictionary = {} and then calling i["store"] and i["store_type] and then creating entries into the new dictionary with new_dict[store] = store_type, but I keep getting a Type Error that says: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Pretty sure it's a dictionary though

Comment: `[

    {

        "description": "abcdefghijklm",
        "previous_orders": [
            {
                "store": "Target",
                "store_type": "Retail"
            }

        ]

    }

]

`

if it's in the brackets, I'm assuming it's a dictionary in a list, but i'm still unsure of how to achieve what i need to

Comment: @sab since it sounds like it probably shouldn't be in a list you could add a line to take it out before running this code. `large_dict = large_dict[0]`.